# How to convert Spark Dense Matrix to a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to implement some code in Scala Spark wherein I have a Multiclass Logistic Regression Model and the model generates a coefficient matrix.

Here is the code -

```
val training = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt")


training.show(false)
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|label|features                                                   |
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|1.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.222222,0.5,-0.762712,-0.833333])          |
|1.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.555556,0.25,-0.864407,-0.916667])         |
|1.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.722222,-0.166667,-0.864407,-0.833333])    |
|1.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.722222,0.166667,-0.694915,-0.916667])     |
|0.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[0.166667,-0.416667,0.457627,0.5])            |
|1.0  |(4,[0,2,3],[-0.833333,-0.864407,-0.916667])                |
|2.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-1.32455E-7,-0.166667,0.220339,0.0833333])   |
|2.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-1.32455E-7,-0.333333,0.0169491,-4.03573E-8])|
|1.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.5,0.75,-0.830508,-1.0])                   |
|0.0  |(4,[0,2,3],[0.611111,0.694915,0.416667])                   |
|0.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[0.222222,-0.166667,0.423729,0.583333])       |
|1.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.722222,-0.166667,-0.864407,-1.0])         |
|1.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.5,0.166667,-0.864407,-0.916667])          |
|2.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.222222,-0.333333,0.0508474,-4.03573E-8])  |
|2.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.0555556,-0.833333,0.0169491,-0.25])       |
|2.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.166667,-0.416667,-0.0169491,-0.0833333])  |
|1.0  |(4,[0,2,3],[-0.944444,-0.898305,-0.916667])                |
|2.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.277778,-0.583333,-0.0169491,-0.166667])   |
|0.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[0.111111,-0.333333,0.38983,0.166667])        |
|2.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[-0.222222,-0.166667,0.0847457,-0.0833333])   |
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

There are 3 labels for which I am trying to fit a model.

```
scala> training.select("label").distinct.show
+-----+
|label|
+-----+
|  0.0|
|  1.0|
|  2.0|
+-----+
```

Fit a Logistic Regression Model

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
val lr = new LogisticRegression().setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.3).setElasticNetParam(0.8)
​
// Fit the model
val lrModel = lr.fit(training)
​
```

Now, when I try to take a look at the coefficient matrix, it gives me a matrix which has 3 rows(for 3 labels) and 4 columns(4 input features)

```
scala> lrModel.coefficientMatrix.toDense
res13: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseMatrix =
0.0  0.0  0.0                  0.3176483191238039
0.0  0.0  -0.7803943459681859  -0.3769611423403096
0.0  0.0  0.0                  0.0
```

and here are the intercepts for each of the labels -

```
scala> lrModel.interceptVector
res15: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector = [0.05165231659832854,-0.12391224990853622,0.07225993331020768]
```

I want to create a feature importance **Spark dataframe** using the coefficient matrix and the intercept vector to get a final resultant dataframe like this -

```
label feature name  coefficient intercept
0         0             0         0.051
0         1             0         0.051
0         2             0         0.051
0         3             0.3176    0.051
1         0             0         -0.123
1         1             0         -0.123
1         2             -0.78     -0.123
1         3             -0.37     -0.123
2         0             0         0.072
2         1             0         0.072
2         2             0         0.072
2         3             0         0.072
```

Every feature has a coefficient for every label, so total records in the output would be `labels * features` which is `3 * 4 = 12`

I would like this process to be dynamic, kind of wrap it up in a function so that I can re use it for any number of features and labels.

I am reading the data from here - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here lr is your pyspark's logistic regression as an example. And below code I tried for multinominal logistic regression

```
weights=lr.coefficientMatrix
rows = weights.toArray().tolist()
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows,["<your list of features columns used for training"])
```

Above code worked from me, don't worry about the sequence assign the order which you have trained